# Refresh only Listboxes inside ModalPopUp on Parent page from the child page

Tags: asp.net, listbox, refresh, updatepanel

Good Day,

May I please ask if someone may have some information that may help me with this issue.

Scenario:
Parent Page: modalpopup updatepanel that contains two listboxes
Child Page:  detailsview

I am updating data in the db from the Child page using a detailsview then I would like the listboxes located in modalpopup updatepanel on the parent to refresh after I click UPDATE on the child page detailsview so as to reflect the changes made on the child page.  Not the whole page, just the two listboxes.  Child page does not close, it can remain open while the parent is open so any "on unload" events or such will not work for this.

I am currently able to update the gridview on the parent as well as some text boxes and dropdowns located in update panels (not modal popups) utilizing the items inserted event and update event of the child's detailsview.

Basically: Parent opens Child page then I am accessing controls on the parent to fire off events on the parent using something like:

- Child: javascript function:

Function updateParentControl(){
window.opener.document.getElementById('btnRefresh_ddl_dropdown').click();}

- Child code behind:

Dim ctlName as string = "ddl_dropdown"

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "updateParentControl", (Convert.ToString("updateParentControl('") & ctlName) + "');", True)

Protected Sub dv_DetailsView_ItemUpdated(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs)

updateParentControl("ddl_dropdown")

End Sub

.......................................

- On the parent: button click code behind

btnRefresh_ddl_dropdown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

ddl_dropdown.DataBind()

End Sub

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my first post on this forum, my apologies for not knowing how to use the grey boxes to encase the code.

D.